# Facebook Graph API - 3.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to call Facebook's Graph API v.3.2 using nuget package?

I was on 7.0.6 (latest stable version of the nuget package) and upgraded to 7.0.10-beta but it still calls Graph API v.2.8. I saw that it's been awhile since the nuget package has been updated.

If it's not possible how should I proceed to call the latest version of Graph API?

Comment: If this doesn’t offer any option to specify the API version to call via configuration (most SDKs do), you could do this via your FB app settings, Settings -> Advanced -> Upgrade API Version

Comment: @04FS I can't seem to find the configuration file of the SDK.